Story where character has "boomerdisc"
Unfortunately, this is all I remember from this story.  This boomerdisc apparently returns when thrown like a boomerang.  I realize it makes for some slim pickings but it's all I have.

Can you at least recall when you read it?

Voting to close, boomer discs are not science fiction.

@Adamant  I was going to say, that's just called a vinyl

@NickS But vinyl is the new hip (or has been for the last decade).  A certain large chain bookstore opened near me. They have a music section that is totally vinyl.  No CDs.

@PeterM True, but a new hip is very boomer

A Google books search turns up Bumsider (1972) by C.C. MacApp.  The blurb on Goodreads says:

THE BARRIER
Jeff Adams stared northward. From this spot he could see over the hummocks and just make out the scarlet glow along the top of the Barrier, though he couldn't see the land along the base. This side, for two hundred miles to the east and to the west, was fallows country: loose, parched soil, except when the infrequent rains barely moistened it and caked the top, too sandy to support any terran plant life. Only a few hundred yards north of the barrier the green fields began. You could lean against the barrier and stare through: the invisble impenetrable force-field wouldn't hurt you, even if you hurled yourself against it. a Bumsider could dream of being inside and wonder what crime or deficiency had got his ancestors exiled to Bumside-but not for long: in Bumside you had to keep moving to keep eating...

"Boomerdisc" crops up frequently in the text:

No sense letting the Incop know he had it.  Instead, he touched his boomerdisc sheath and thrower to make sure they were handy.


When he was sure he had them all, he removed the boomerdiscs from his carrying sheath and hid the coins in the bottom.  Then he stood glaring murderously after the now distant grav car.  That damned snotty Incop!

But it seems they are more like frisbees than boomerangs; the story talks about curving their flight, but not them returning:

[...]grasseaters pacing silently from the woods, their riders' heads swiftly turning as they caught sight of Jeff's father seated with his back to them.  Then one had put a disc in his thrower, drawn back his arm, and slung!  He must have been left-handed to send the missile curving out away from the grove then sharply in toward its target!  The faint rasp of its release from the thrower pouch must have been drowned out by his father's whittling.


It was going to be a very difficult throw—sixty yards, at least, and it would have to curve more than ten yards out of that line and go in at a definite angle to be sure of missing[...]

As an aside, just based on all the typos I've found in relatively few snippets, this was not a high-quality production.

I have to point out that not all boomerangs return.  If you are hunting with one, you want a boomerang that flies true, straight to your target and delivers a damaging blow.  You don't want one that flies an uncontrolled path that makes it very hard to predict where the impact will occur.

@PeterM True enough, and certainly any boomerang that hits will definitely not return.  (Contrary to most portrayals in comics.)  I'm responding to the question, which expects that behaviour of boomerangs.

C C MacApp's novel Bumsider includes this excerpt

The man that slung the boomerdisc was careless

There's not much about it online, but this Amazon page has this quote which might spark a memory

A Bumsider could dream of being inside and wonder what crime or
deficiency had got his ancestors exiled to Bumside-but not for long:
in Bumside you had to keep moving to keep eating...

